# Is the $t^5+15t+12=0$ equation congruent with the Galois group?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, galois-theory, quintics

[image]

> Is the quintic equation: $t^5+15t+12=0$ congruent with the Galois group?

And is it true that Lagrange tells us that there are other methods, which that we do not know for the quintic equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent with the Galois group"

Comment: Ohh, google translate is wrong..I fix now

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, but the Galois group of that polynomial is a group of order 20 and hence is a solvable group, thus it can be solved in radicals.

Comment: I understood...

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to see whether the quintic equation is solvable, you can use Cayley's resolvent outlined in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) on quintic functions. But beware: you invite much larger numbers than those in the original quintic.

In the Cayley resolvent method, a quintic equation

$y^5+py^3+qy^2+ry+s=0$

is solvable if the resolvent sextic

$[P_3(z)]^2-1024z\Delta$

has a rational zero, where $\Delta$ and the coefficients of the cubic polynomial are evaluated from the coefficients of the reduced quintic.

Here $p=q=0$, which simplifies the cubic polynomial and the discriminant $\Delta$. For this case the formulas given in the Wikipedia article reduce to

$P_3(z)=z^3-20rz^2+240r^2z+320r^3$

$\Delta=3125s^4+256r^5$

For this case $r=15,s=12$ we get

$(z^3-300z^2+54000z+1080000)^2-(1024)(259200000z)=0.$

The discriminant  $\Delta=259200000=2592×100000$ factors as $2^{10}×3^4×5^5$, so it's $5$ times a perfect square. Then $z$ must also be $5$ times a perfect square if the $1024z\Delta$ term is to match the squared cubic polynomial.

We try out candidates of the form $z=5n^2$, where $n|1080000$, starting from $n=1$ and increasing until either we hit a zero or the cubic polynomial becomes positive and its square exceeds the more slowly increasing $1024z\Delta$ term. In this case we hit a rational zero at $n=6$ ($z=180$), and so prove that the quintic $y^5+15y+12=0$ is solvable.

As a shortcut, we may note that apart from the leading term in the $P_3$ polynomial, all terms are forced to be divisible by the prime factors $2,3,5$. So $z$ must also have these factors for the leading term in $P_3$ to match making $5×(2×3)^2=180$ the smallest (and successful) candidate for $z$.

Getting the actual roots, however, is much more complicated. According to Wikipedia, an explicit formula for the quintic roots, given the polynomial coefficients and a rational resolvent root (the number $180$ identified above), runs three pages and was not published until 2004.